# Multiple zend action helpers

Tags: zend-framework

I have the following command in my bootstrap

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath( APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers', 'Application_Controller_Helper_');
```

and I call these action helpers from my controller as followed

```
$this->_helper->myHelper
```

To keep things more organize, I want to have multiple folders in my `/controller/helpers` folders. How can I call on these functions then? Cause when I use `$this->_helper->myFolder->myAction` it is assuming I am calling the file `MyFolder` and the function `MyAction` within that file!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call it this wy:

```
$helperAction = $this->_helper->MyFolder_MyHelper->myAction();
```

here are the docs describing naming conventions:
[coding-standard.naming-conventions.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html#coding-standard.naming-conventions.classes)